# Joining tables on a non-key column and eliminating duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates, left-join

I have inherited a very poorly structured database and am tasked with deriving useful information from it. I have two tables, Transactions and CodeDefinitions.

This is a simplified example of the Transactions table

```
ID (primary key)
CodeName (varchar(50))
Description(varchar(255)
TranDate (datetime)
Amount (money)
```

Simplified structure of the CodeDefinitions table

```
ID (primary key)
Name (varchar(50))
Description (varchar(255))
```

Example data from both tables

Transactions Table (contains 500,000 rows of transactions)

```
ID      CodeName    Description             TranDate    Amount
510348  HRCUT       Haircut                 2017-11-02  30.00
510349  RINSE       Rinse - Extra Deluxe    2017-11-02  45.00
510350  PERM        Luxury Perm             2017-11-02  80.00
510351  HRCUT       Haircut                 2017-11-02  30.00
```

CodeDefinitions Table (2000 rows of nothing but SKUs)

```
ID      Name        Description
684     RINSE       Rinse - Extra Deluxe
686     HRCUT       Haircut
730     PERM        Luxury Perm
2203    HRCUT       Haircut (note the duplicate name and description!)
```

The previous database developer did not bother to set a UNIQUE constraint on CodeDefinitions.Code or even a FK constraint on Transactions.Code. So what this means is that users are able to enter in identical CodeDefinitions.Name with the only difference being CodeDefinitions.ID. Because the Transactions table contains only the Name and Description of the particular CodeDefinition and not the ID, this has been hell on attempting to filter out duplicates

What I would like to do is to be able to accurately sum the monetary amount of how many haircuts have been sold for the given time date by JOINING on Transactions.CodeID to eliminate duplicates. If two SKUs have the same name, choose the highest CodeDefinitions.ID. I would like to avoid using DISTINCT, GROUP BY, or MAX if at all possible since these take the query execution time from 5s to 5 minutes (unless there was something wrong with the way I wrote the query, I’m not too familiar with the MySQL optimizer)

I have attempted to `Left JOIN on t.CodeName = cd.Name`, but that returns all `CodeDefinitions.ID` as `NULL`. I need to be able to `SELECT the CodeDefinitions.ID`for filtering purposes.

My query:

```
SELECT
t.ID   AS TranID
, t.CodeName AS ProcedureCode
, cd.ID  AS CodeID
, Description
, t.TranDate
, t.Amount
FROM transactions t
LEFT OUTER JOIN CodeDefinitions cd ON (T.Description = cd.Description)
WHERE TranDate BETWEEN '2017-11-1' AND '2017-11-31'
```

Expected result:

```
TranID  ProcedureCode CodeID Description            TranDate    TranAmt
510348  HRCUT         2203   Haircut                2017-11-02  30.00
510349  RINSE         684    Rinse - Extra Deluxe   2017-11-02  45.00
510350  PERM          730    Luxury Perm            2017-11-02  80.00
510351  HRCUT         2203   Haircut                2017-11-02  30.00
```

Actual result:

```
TranID  ProcedureCode CodeID Description          TranDate   TranAmt
510348  HRCUT         686    Haircut              2017-11-02 30.00
510348  HRCUT         2203   Haircut              2017-11-02 30.00
510349  RINSE         684    Rinse - Extra Deluxe 2017-11-02 45.00
510350  PERM          730    Luxury Perm          2017-11-02 80.00
510351  HRCUT         686    Haircut              2017-11-02 30.00
510351  HRCUT         2203   Haircut              2017-11-02 30.00
```

How do you get rid of these duplicates and choose the highest CodeID among each set of duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a grouped subselect to find distinct codes with the highest ID, since your IDs appear to be numeric -

```
SELECT t.ID AS TranID, t.CodeName AS ProcedureCode, cd.ID AS CodeID,
    cd.Description, t.TranDate, t.Amount
FROM (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, Name FROM CodeDefinitions GROUP BY Name) ss
JOIN CodeDefinitions cd 
ON cd.name = ss.name AND cd.ID = ss.ID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
transactions t
ON (T.CodeName = cd.Name)
WHERE TranDate BETWEEN '2017-11-1' AND '2017-11-31'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f553ba/7)

This will eliminate the code definitions that have the same name as another from your select. If you want to actually remove them from the database -

```
DELETE FROM CodeDefinitions
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM CodeDefinitions GROUP BY Name) ss
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the CodeDefinitions Table is having lesser data it wont be costly to apply a ranking on it to select the row with max ID from the group. So we can first find out the max ID for each Name in CodeDefinitions table. We can then use it in left outer join with Transactions Table.

```
SELECT
t.ID   AS TranID
, t.CodeName AS ProcedureCode
, cd.ID  AS CodeID
, Description
, t.TranDate
, t.Amount
FROM transactions t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from 
(select ID,Name,rank() over (parition by name order by ID desc) as rnum from CodeDefinitions) 
where rnum=1) cd 
ON (T.Description = cd.Name)
WHERE TranDate BETWEEN '2017-11-1' AND '2017-11-31'
```

What i have done is just replaced your Codedefinitions table with view of Codedefinitions having no duplicate and containing only the row with max ID for each distinct Name.